# How to pass an image between Activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to click a button from `Activity 1` with image to show an image for `Activity 2`, but it's not working.

Activity1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
// Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Drawable drawable=img1.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap= ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

intent.putExtra("picture", b);
// String ten = edt.getText().toString();
// bundle.putString("tenkh", ten);
// intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
TextView txtTen= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
Intent goiIntent=getIntent();
Bundle extras = goiIntent.getExtras();
byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("picture");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

*You should show us the logical to help us understand the problem.*

However i think your problem is that the `byte []` is to big to be pass in an intent.

One workaround could be to have an abstract class with a public static field of type `byte[]`. Before broadcasting your intent, set this field with your data and in the next activity read this data **and don't forget to set the field to `null` when you don't need it to avoid memory leak.**

Create a class `ImageHelper` as follow :

```
public abstract class ImageHelper {
    public static byte [] image;
}
```

In your activity 1, before launching the intent, instead of `intent.putExtra("picture", b);` use `ImageHelper.image = b;`

Then in your activity 2, instead of `byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("picture");`, you use `byte[] b = ImageHelper.image;`.

Comment: i cant show image from activity 1 to activity 2, can you give me solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
Activity 1
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);

Activity 2
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to pass a Bitmap in an Intent because it's very costly. Instead, pass around URIs or any other location mechanism (file path, etc.).  There's an un-documented limit of 1MB which has been tested by other developers and anyway using extras is discouraged by Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5878